# ios populating sqlite database error, final entries are not written

Tags: ios, sqlite, sigabrt

**UPDATED QUESTION, check the end of the post**

I am making an iPhone app and I want when the user first lunches the app, for the app to create a new database and populate it with the data of a plist file.

Here is my view did load code:

```
//get database path
NSString *symptomDatabasePath = [self symptomsDatabasePath];

//check if database exists and initialize if it doesn't
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:symptomDatabasePath])
{
    [self createAndPopulateDatabase];
}
```

My symptomDatabasePath function:

```
//get the path of the symptoms database
- (NSString *) symptomsDatabasePath
{
NSArray *pathsArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [pathsArray objectAtIndex:0];
return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"symptoms.sqlite"];
}
```

And finally my createANdPopulateDatabase function:

```
- (void) createAndPopulateDatabase
{
//get query to insert symptoms into database
NSArray *pathsArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [pathsArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databaseDataFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"symptomsDatabaseList.plist"];
NSString *symptomData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:databaseDataFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

sqlite3 *database;
if (sqlite3_open([[self symptomsDatabasePath] UTF8String], &database)!=SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
}

NSString *createTableQuery = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_symptoms (symptomCode varchar(15) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,title varchar(255) NOT NULL,shortTitle varchar(255) NOT NULL,inclusions varchar(255) NOT NULL,exclusions varchar(255) NOT NULL,symptomCategory varchar(255) NOT NULL);";

char *errorMsg;
//create new table
if(sqlite3_exec(database, [createTableQuery UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errorMsg)!=SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSAssert(0, @"Error creating table: %s", errorMsg);
}

NSString *insertQueryString = @"INSERT INTO tbl_symptoms (symptomCode, title, shortTitle, inclusions, exclusions, symptomCategory) VALUES ";
//array containing the seperate symptom data
NSArray *symptomArray = [symptomData componentsSeparatedByString:@"),"];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
//nsmutable array with all queries
NSMutableArray *queryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//loop through the aray with symptoms build queries and store them in an array
for(int i=0; i<[symptomArray count]; i++)
{
     //create query string with insert command
    NSMutableString *insertString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:insertQueryString];
    //append the specific symptoms data
    [insertString appendString:[symptomArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    [insertString appendString:@");"];
    [queryArray insertObject:insertString atIndex:i];
}

    //insert data into database

for(int i=0; i<[queryArray count]; i++)
{
    const char *insertChar = [[queryArray objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insertChar, -1, &statement, nil)!=SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert(0, @"Error filling table: %s", errorMsg);
    }
    if (sqlite3_step(statement)!=SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSAssert(0, @"Error inserting data into database: %s", errorMsg);
    }
    //finalize changes
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

My code is a bit messy because i have been trying various solutions. Anyway I have the data I want to input written like this in my phlist file:

*('Z27', 'Fear of a social problem', 'Fear of a social problem', 'concern about/fear of having a social problem', 'if the patient has a social problem, code the problem ', 'Social problems’),
('Z28', 'Limited  function/disability (Z)', 'Limited function/disability (Z)', '', '', 'Social problems’),
('Z29', 'Social problem NOS', 'Social problem NOS', 'environmental problems; malingering', '', 'Social problems’*

there are 320 such entries in my file, these are the last 3 because they are the ones I am having trouble with.

The app copies all the other 317 entries, but not these 3. And I know it is missing a ) at the end, but that's because my code appends it on every loop.

I get a SIGABRT error and the following error code:

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error filling table: (null)'"

Can anyone help me? I probably have done something wrong with sqlite3, though I don't understand why it only doesn't copy the last 3 entries.

Also earlier it wouldn't copy only the last entry, but after I copy pasted it around to see if it was a problem with the entry itself, it started not copying the last 3 :S.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

**UPDATE**

So it turns out I was getting the errors cause I was using NSAssert. Now I am using NSLogs to log my errors, and the app launches correctly, but I still get the error when copying the final 3 entries.

According to my logs moth the sqlite3_prepare_v2 and the sqlite3_step functions fail, but ONLY for the final 3 entries :S

Comment: Where in your code does it crash? What are you building your query with a mutable string instead of using `sqlite3_bind_xxx` to bind the value into a single, prepared statement?

Comment: it crashes on the final loops. I found that online but I didn't understand the instructions well. Should I bind each insert separately  all the entire query together and then run it?

Comment: Which exact line of code crashes?

Comment: So it turns out I was getting the errors cause I was using NSAssert. Now I am using NSLogs to log my errors, and the app launches correctly, but I still get the error when copying the final 3 entries. I will update the question with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have smart quotes. For example, I see you have

```
..., 'Social problems’), ...
```

Note, you're starting that with a standard apostrophe, but finishing it with a closing single quote. If you look very carefully, they look different.

Replace those smart quotes with standard apostrophe and that should fix the immediate problem.

---

I'd suggest you log the SQL and carefully examine it. Also, when the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` fails, you are not logging the appropriate error message. You can do something like:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insertChar, -1, &statement, nil)!=SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"prepare failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSAssert(0, @"Error filling table");
}
```

Comment: The OP is checking the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` result but logging the wrong error. In fact, the wrong error is logged for most of the failure checks. OP - use `sqlite3_errmsg` to get the error.

Comment: Should also point out that the query should only be prepared once, before the loop, assuming the code is updated to properly use `sqlite3_bind_xxx` for each value.

Comment: Following a tutorial (just getting the hangs on using sqlite3 with xcode), so any links with some well written tutorials to help me learn will be very appreciated.

Comment: @YannisP. No specific link but be sure you find one that makes proper use of `sqlite3_bind_text` (or other similar functions) and `sqlite3_reset` to perform `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Ok I will. But any idea why this problem might only appear in the final 3 entries?

Comment: @YannisP. Until you log the `sqlite3_errmsg`, we won't know what the error was, and it's hard to fix it without knowing what the error is. This approach of starting with a long string of values is highly questionable, but it doesn't makes sense to worry about that until we know what's wrong. And, in answer to your question about "why this problem might only appear in the final 3 entries?", you are only performing three insert statements (on the basis of your example), so it means they're all failing. Look at the error message to know why.

Comment: I am inserting 320 entries together, not just 3. But only the final 3 don't get inserted. BTW I added sql3_errmsg and this is the error message I got for each entry (only going to paste the first of the 3 entries) : 2014-10-24 18:08:39.640 add_symptoms_prototype_version_1[2669:70195] Error filling table for entry number unrecognized token: "'Social problems‚Äô);"
2014-10-24 18:08:39.641 add_symptoms_prototype_version_1[2669:70195] Error inserting data into database for entry number unrecognized token: "'Social problems‚Äô);"

Comment: I just copied the final 3 entries here, just in case there's something wrong with them

Comment: @YannisP. Great. Armed with an error message, the problem now jumps out at us: Look at the closing single quote. It's not the standard apostrophe character, but a closing quote. Replace those `’` characters with `'`. I don't know how you built that input string, but it's really susceptible to these sorts of problems.

Comment: a lot of different badly written tutorials, and working at 4AM on it ended me up with this badly written string xD. Anyway, once I've gottent his working I'll go around learning to use the bind_text statement. Thanks for the help :)